# Azure Kubernetes Service: What about PV and PVC in Stateful workload migration to new nodepool of different machine size

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-statefulset

**Context:**
[Regarding cost reduction for compute]. In AKS cluster, recently observed that compute resources are under-utilised and so my plan is:

1. To create a new node pool(with lower cpu and memory, and so lower cost basically) and attach to the same AKS cluster.
   And then
2. cordon the old node pool and then drain it, so the workload will move to new node pool (Thanks to nodeSelector)

**Question:**

What about the k8s resources like statefulset for eg. Redis etc which are in old node pool and are having PV and PVC . Do we have to take backup of those pvc and restore etc for new node pool? (As per my thinking, kubernetes will take care of detaching and attaching pvc considering all this activity will be within single kubernetes cluster only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right! Kubernetes will take care of detaching and attaching PV and PVC considering all this activity will be within single Kubernetes cluster only. You don’t need to backup.

(If the response was helpful please don't forget to upvote and/or accept as answer, thank you)